# How to execute multiple opened files?

Tags: c++-cli

This is how my task gonna be,

I have created a GUI which consist of two buttons as shown,

[image]

So, for the "browse captured file" button, I would have to open multiple files through OpenFIleDialog and read it. This is the code for open and read files.

```
Stream^ myStream;

OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1->Title = "open captured file";
openFileDialog1->Filter = "CP files (*.cp)|*.cp|All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1->Multiselect = true;

if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
     {

for each (String^ file in openFileDialog1->FileNames) 
{  

       array<String^>^ lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(file);  

     for each (String^ line in lines) 
     {          
     }
}
```

}

After that, I would like to start implementation on each files. Files that I opened for example "1_1.cp", "2_1.cp" and "3_1.cp". At the "Start Analysis" button, I will start doing analysis on the files and need to assign each files to do different task or function.

Now my question is, how am I going to assign each opened files to do specific task or function. For example, 1_1.cp do task A, 2_1.cp do task B and so on? Anyone can help to suggest some ideas?

I want to make it as an automated system.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: What exactly does “assign each files to do different task or function” mean? And why do you need to do that? Are you asking how to process the files in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define yourself a worker-method for the `System::Threading::ThreadPool` and as you analyzed a line, queue an item to the `ThreadPool`.

```
 for each (String^ line in lines) 
 {
    System::Threading::ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem( gcnew WaitCallback(YourMethod), dataToPass);    
 }
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) for `ThreadPool`.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of doing this? 

Cause I want to assign the opened files into the "start analysis" and begin the analysis function. May I know does both button linked? Meaning that the files opened in "browse captured file" can be read in "start analysis" ? Thanks.

Comment: Using this method, you will create a thread that performs a task given by you. I don't know about dependencies and passing of your data internally. I am not quite sure if I got you right, though...